# cannot generate log when use curl send post request

Tags: python, http, curl, flask

I am trying to test register function for my flask app.

```
curl -X POST -H "application/json" -d "email=12345671111@qqcom&name=test123"  http://192.168.50.4:5000/register
{
  "message": "\u9519\u8bef\u7684 JSON \u6570\u636e\u683c\u5f0f"
}%
```

The return message is very strange, and the flask log show:

```
"POST /register HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

but if I click register button in webpage, it is normal.

```
192.168.50.1 - - [15/Nov/2015 13:16:49] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 400 -
192.168.50.1 - - [15/Nov/2015 13:22:03] "OPTIONS /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
the params is {u'fullname': u'test11828732', u'email': u'hshdshhvhd@qq.com'}
```

no idea for this, hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: The return message would be very interesting.

Comment: @KlausD. but I don't know what is the meaning?

Comment: OK in other words: If you add the response to your post, it would help us to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @KlausD. I know the message info: wrong json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you didn't pass valid JSON data.  Your curl command is incorrect: you didn't set the content type header correctly and you passed form encoded data rather than JSON data.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"email": "12345671111@qq.com", "name": "test123"}'
```